# Oracle 11g get data from 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get a record from one table and on the basis of that record sum of quantity in another table which has multiple record and then join thrid table to get the price and multiply price with quantity.

order

| id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 25-12-2022 |

orderitem

| id | pid | qty | Uom(unit of measure) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 5 | KG |
| 1 | 101 | 10 | KG |
| 1 | 102 | 15 | KG |

productstable

| pid | price | Uom(unit of measure) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | KG |
| 101 | 2 | KG |
| 102 | 3 | KG |

OUTPUT:

| date | quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25-12-2022 | 30 | 70 |

1-Get record from order

2-Sum quantity of that id

3-get price of product id and multiply it with sum quantity in step 2

Comment: SELECT ORR.DATE,ORR.ID,ORI.QTY,PT.PRICE
    FROM ORDERS ORR
    JOIN ORDER_ITEM  ORI ON ORR.ID=ORI.ID
    JOIN PRODUCTSTABLE PT ON ORI.PID=PT.PID

I guess, you can start with this one

Comment: You described `sum(qty) * price` but clearly want `sum(qty * price)`. So, what have you actually tried?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the question you need the sum per order id *( 2-Sum quantity of that id )*. If that is the case then you'll need order id for grouping the data:

```sql
SELECT      o.ID "ORDER_ID", o.ORDER_DATE,
            Sum(oi.QTY) "QTY", Sum(oi.QTY * p.PRICE) "AMOUNT"
FROM        order_tbl o
INNER JOIN  order_items oi ON(oi.ID = o.ID)
INNER JOIN  products p ON(p.PID = oi.PID)
GROUP BY    o.ID,  o.ORDER_DATE
ORDER BY    o.ID
```

With your sample data (added a few more rows):

```sql
with
    order_tbl (ID, STATUS, ORDER_DATE) AS
        (   
            Select 1, 1, To_Date('2022-12-25', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 1, To_Date('2022-12-25', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 1, To_Date('2022-12-25', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual 
        ),
    order_items (ID, PID, QTY, UOM) AS
        (
            Select 1, 100,  5, 'KG' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 101, 10, 'KG' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 102, 15, 'KG' From Dual Union All
      --  added order 2
            Select 2, 101, 15, 'KG' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 100, 15, 'KG' From Dual Union All
      --  added order 3
            Select 3, 102, 10, 'KG' From Dual 
        ),
    products (PID, PRICE, UOM) as
        (
            Select 100, 1, 'KG' From Dual Union All
            Select 101, 2, 'KG' From Dual Union All
            Select 102, 3, 'KG' From Dual
        )
```

R e s u l t :

| ORDER_ID | ORDER_DATE | QTY | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25-DEC-22 | 30 | 70 |
| 2 | 25-DEC-22 | 30 | 45 |
| 3 | 25-DEC-22 | 10 | 30 |

And if you need dayly subtotals - u can use MODEL  clause like here...

```sql
SELECT  
    ORDER_ID "ORDER_ID", ORDER_DATE, QTY, AMOUNT
FROM    ( SELECT        CAST(To_Char(o.ID) as VarChar2(20)) "ORDER_ID", o.ORDER_DATE,
                    Sum(oi.QTY) "QTY", Sum(oi.QTY * p.PRICE) "AMOUNT"
          FROM      order_tbl o
          INNER JOIN    order_items oi ON(oi.ID = o.ID)
          INNER JOIN    products p ON(p.PID = oi.PID)
          GROUP BY  o.ID,  o.ORDER_DATE
          ORDER BY  o.ID  )
MODEL 
    PARTITION BY  (ORDER_DATE)
    DIMENSION BY  (ORDER_ID)
    MEASURES      (QTY, AMOUNT)
    RULES     (  QTY['Total for Date']    = Sum(QTY)[ORDER_ID != 'Total for Date'],
                 AMOUNT['Total for Date'] = Sum(AMOUNT)[ORDER_ID != 'Total for Date'])
ORDER BY ORDER_DATE, ORDER_ID
```

which (with some more sample data [id = 4]) results as:

| ORDER_ID | ORDER_DATE | QTY | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25-DEC-22 | 30 | 70 |
| 2 | 25-DEC-22 | 30 | 45 |
| 3 | 25-DEC-22 | 10 | 30 |
| Total for Date | 25-DEC-22 | 70 | 145 |
| 4 | 26-DEC-22 | 22 | 44 |
| Total for Date | 26-DEC-22 | 22 | 44 |

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  t_order (id, status, datum) as
  3    (select 1, 1, date '2022-12-22' from dual),
  4  orderitem (id, pid, qty) as
  5    (select 1, 100, 5 from dual union all
  6     select 1, 101, 10 from dual union all
  7     select 1, 102, 15 from dual
  8    ),
  9  productstable (pid, price) as
 10    (select 100, 1 from dual union all
 11     select 101, 2 from dual union all
 12     select 102, 3 from dual
 13    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 14  select o.datum,
 15    sum(i.qty) quantity,
 16    sum(i.qty * p.price) price
 17  from t_order o join orderitem i on i.id = o.id
 18                 join productstable p on p.pid = i.pid
 19  group by o.datum;

DATUM        QUANTITY      PRICE
---------- ---------- ----------
22-12-2022         30         70

SQL>
```

(I renamed invalid table (`order`) and column (`date`) names).